# How to position several widgets side by side, on one line, with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

By default, after making a tkinter button, **it automatically puts the next one on the other line**.
How do I stop this from happening?
I want to do something like this:
[image]

Comment: Please provide code, so we can see where you can fix it. Probably a minimal GUI with two buttons extracted from you code should be enough.

Comment: You can put a single horizontal box, and then fill it with your buttons. The default is probably a vertical box. (Sorry I have not used tk for a long time, so don't remember the names.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must use one of the geometry managers for that:

**here with `grid`:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='b1')
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='b2')
b1.grid(column=0, row=0)   # grid dynamically divides the space in a grid
b2.grid(column=1, row=0)   # and arranges widgets accordingly
root.mainloop()
```

**there using `pack`:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='b1')
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='b2')
b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)      # pack starts packing widgets on the left 
b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)      # and keeps packing them to the next place available on the left
root.mainloop()
```

The remaining geometry manager is `place`, but its use is sometimes complicated when resizing of the GUI occurs.

Comment: Is there a reason why you put `b1.grid(column=0, row=0)` twice? Anyway, this works like intended. thanks.

Comment: I'll add a tick in 8 minutes, i cannot do that now :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this to make the y coordinates the same and change the x coordinate:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

Button(root, text='Submit', width=10, bg='blue', fg='white', 
command=database).place(x=70, y=130)
```

For the second button:

```
buttonSignIn = Button(root, text="Sign in", width=10, bg='black', 
fg='white', command=new_winF).place(x=30, y=130)
```

Comment: This works too, but @Reblochon Masque made it easier, as I am a beginner to GUI programming, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, and found this: two "simple" ways to move widgets around a GUI area, are

i) Using the ".grid" attribute (see example below):

```
MyButton_FilePath = Button(
                           master  = gui,
                           text    = 'Open',
                           command = funcion_openfile_findpath,
                           fg      = 'Black', font = ('Arial bold',11)
                          )
MyButton_FilePath.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)
```

ii) Or using the attribute ".place":

```
MyButton_FilePath = Button(
                           master  = gui,
                           text    = 'Open',
                           command = funcion_openfile_findpath,
                           fg      = 'Black', font = ('Arial bold',11)
                          )
MyButton_FilePath.place(x=300, y=400)
```

Note that I have separated the "Button" object into two lines - as it is considered to be a better practice whenever placing/gridding widgets...

Hope I have helped.

Try both ways and see which one fits better your wishes! :)

Cheers, Marcos Moro, PhD

Comment: Your customtkinter wasn't back in future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have come up with uses the newer Custom TK inter module within a canvas.
The buttons can be on the same row as another button if you use the sticky tag in the grid position.

```
 CTkLabel(button_canvas, text="Gain", font=("Courier", 14)).grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10, padx=15)
 CTkButton(button_canvas, text="^", command=self.gain_up, width=30).grid(row=6, column=1, padx=15, sticky="W")
 CTkButton(button_canvas, text="v", command=self.gain_down, width=30).grid(row=6, column=1, padx=15)
```

Works a treat.